# How to programmatically insert a plugin into a web page in Chrome content script?

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to insert a plugin I created into a page using a content script in a Google Chrome extension. According to the documentation:
"If your plugin is "public", you can even use a content script to programmatically insert your plugin into a web page."
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Unfortunately the examples they give do not inject a plugin programmatically. In the 'background.html' file I embed the plugin using:

and then I can get the plugin by simply calling:
document.getElementById('myPlugin')

How do I do this in a javascript content script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean you need to use the content script to insert the `embed` tag and information: (psuedo code)

```
function addIt(){
  myEmbed = document.createElement('embed');
  myEmbed.attributes(add your attributes so easy with jquery);
  document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].append('myEmbed');
}
```

Comment: Here are a couple of links that might be helpful to you while working with npapi: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/e6b6cc9f9036eca0      ....and....  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XEmbed_Extension_for_Mozilla_Plugins

Comment: Hmm when I try to call the plugin method I get "Uncaught error: Error calling method on NPObject" any ideas?

Comment: `function addIt(){

  myEmbed = document.createElement('embed');


  myEmbed.setAttribute("type", "application/x-myPlugin");

  myEmbed.setAttribute("id", "myPlugin");

  document.getElementById("LikePluginPagelet").appendChild(myEmbed);
}

//In a separate function

var plugin = document.getElementById('myPlugin');

plugin().connectMe(false, false, "Hello", "Parameter", "");
`
Jeez I'm not sure how to format this its not formatting it properly.

Comment: O wait I actually got it. The last line should just be: plugin.connectMe(...). Thanks for your help!